# Ionic app stopped and still load in splash screen just in ios device or emulator

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

[image: splashscreen]

App build and run succeed for ios.
The application works without any problems in an android device but stop in the start page when i run it for ios.

Comment: Have you already looked for errors in your `XCode` our Safari Web Developer Console?

Comment: all is done, the app build and run succeed :/

Comment: Did you find the answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to put this in your controller

/** Stop Splash Screen **/

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.loaded', function() {
    ionic.Platform.ready( function() {
       if(navigator && navigator.splashscreen) navigator.splashscreen.hide();
        });
    });
```

Comment: Yes i already try. Also still load after splash screen, but i can't click button or choose item from list...

Answer (score 0):

I tried like this. I used "@awesome-cordova-library/splashscreen" instead of "@ionic-native/splash-screen".

Fixed like this in my case. https://streamable.com/8ryajf
Actually, I posted this...
[Stuck on the splash screen when I run the Ionic on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73612691/12176524)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using capacitor. It's compatible with Android and iOS devices. This might work for you

```
// Capacitor 

npm install @capacitor/splash-screen
npx cap sync

import { SplashScreen as Capsplash } from '@capacitor/splash-screen';

setTimeout(() => {
   Capsplash.hide({
     fadeOutDuration: 1000,
   });
}, 3000);
```

https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/splash-screen

```
// Cordova

ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-splashscreen 
npm install @awesome-cordova-plugins/splash-screen 

import { SplashScreen } from '@awesome-cordova-plugins/splash-screen/ngx';

constructor(private splashScreen: SplashScreen) { }

this.splashScreen.show();

this.splashScreen.hide();
```

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/splash-screen

Answer (score -1):

you try this code in .run() function(app.js). This works for iOS.

```
setTimeout(function() {
navigator.splashscreen.hide();
}, 2000);
```

you can change duration.