# Stuck on the splash screen when I run the Ionic on iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework, splash-screen

I will be able to share the plugins list, too.

Here is the environment.

[image]

Comment: Here is video link.
https://vimeo.com/747193082

Answer (score 2):

When I tried on another mac, the same issue appeared.
Even though the code was working on the previous mac, the splash screen was not disappeared. It seems the screen was frozen in this step.

I found the issue in my case,
Actually, I changed the Xcode setting into **"Rosetta"**(Someone was changed this setting).
After changing this setting into **"Default"**, I can run the app in the original way.
Then, it worked, correctly.